# How to show default page when requested url does not exist?

Tags: html, redirect

When I miss the spelling of an URL or I click a dead (sub)link on a webpage,  quite often I see a default / normalized / standard page telling me that the site I presumably want to visit probably doesn't exist.

Can I include this in my site without using JavaScript? Is there a way to simply include this in an already existing set of files and folders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is sorted either through your hosting company or through a .htaccess file:

```
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch 
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
```

Read up on custom 404 pages or faulty URL redirects.

Comment: This solution is a bad idea. You should use a custom 404 page rather than returning a `200 OK' for every page that doesn't exist.

Comment: `ErrorDocument 404 /index.html` would achieve much the same effect, but preserve the proper "not found" status code to be search engine friendly